# ToggleButtons en Cardview y ReciclerView, solo funciona el ultimo toggle

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

Llevo ya varios días con este problema que no se como solucionar. Tengo varios `CardViews` que pueblan un `ReciclerView`. En cada `CardView` hay `ToggleButton`. Al pulsar el toggle, ejecuta una petición `http` a un servidor.

Todo eso funciona bien. Cuando el server responde, quiero que automáticamente se cambie de estado el `toggle`. Esto funciona solo con el ultimo `toggle` ubicado en el ultimo `CardView` del `ReciclerView`.

He estado mirando los logs y cuando pulso otro toggle, envía bien el comando al servidor, este responde, pero el cambio de estado solo se da en el ultimo toggle.

**Este es mi adaptador:**

```
public class AdaptadorRele extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

String estadoRele01,estadoRele02,estadoRele03,estadoRele04,estadoIp;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DatosRele> data= Collections.emptyList();
DatosRele current;
int currentPos=0;
RelativeLayout lytFondo;

ToggleButton btnActivarRele;
ImageView imgFuncionamiento;
TextView txtKey;

List<String> estadoBotones = new ArrayList<>();

String ac;
String estadoRealBoton="";



public AdaptadorRele(Context context, List<DatosRele> data) {

    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;


}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rele_inicio_cardview, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;



}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    MyHolder miContenedor= (MyHolder) holder;
    current=data.get(position);

    miContenedor.txtId.setText(String.format("%s",current.id));
    miContenedor.txtNombre_Rele.setText(current.nombre_Rele);
    miContenedor.txtKey.setText(current.key);
    miContenedor.txtIp.setText(current.ip);
    miContenedor.txtcmd_On.setText(current.cmd_On);
    miContenedor.txtcmd_Off.setText(current.cmd_Off);
    miContenedor.txtActivo.setText(current.habilitado);
    miContenedor.txtStatus.setText(current.status);


    estadoBotones.add(miContenedor.txtActivo.getText().toString());



    if(current.habilitado.equals("PULSO")){

        imgFuncionamiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.pulso);

    }else{

        imgFuncionamiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
    }


        if (current.status.equals("ON")){

            btnActivarRele.setChecked(true);
        }else {


            btnActivarRele.setChecked(false);
        }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return data.size();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    TextView txtId;
    TextView txtNombre_Rele;
    TextView txtKey;
    TextView txtIp;
    TextView txtcmd_On;

    TextView txtcmd_Off;
    TextView txtActivo;
    TextView txtStatus;

    ImageButton imgAjustesRele;
    ImageButton imgBorrarRele;
   // ImageView imgFuncionamiento;
   // ToggleButton btnActivarRele;





    public MyHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtId =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
        txtNombre_Rele =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreRele);
        txtKey=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
        txtIp=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtIP);
        txtcmd_On=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCmdOn);
        txtcmd_Off =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCmdOff);

        txtActivo =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textActivado);

        txtStatus =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        imgAjustesRele =(ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtn_Ajustes);
        imgBorrarRele =(ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnBorrar_Rele);
        imgFuncionamiento = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFuncionamiento);
        btnActivarRele =(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnOnOff);


        btnActivarRele.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                estadoRealBoton=estadoBotones.get(getAdapterPosition());

                if (b) {


                    if(estadoRealBoton.equals("PULSO")){


                        // Creamos una tarea de delay
                        TimerTask retraso = new TimerTask() {



                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                // Al acabar el tiempo de delay creamos una llamada con intent a la clase MainActivity
                              //  new enviarComandos().execute("http://" + txtIp.getText().toString() + "/?" + txtcmd_Off.getText().toString());
                                btnActivarRele.setChecked(false);


                            }
                        };

                        // Creamos un contador timer y le pasamos como parametro el TimerTask retraso y el delay que hemos definido antes
                        Timer timer = new Timer();
                        timer.schedule(retraso, Long.parseLong(txtKey.getText().toString()));


                    }

                    new enviarComandos().execute("http://" + txtIp.getText().toString() + "/?" + txtcmd_On.getText().toString());

                 //   Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),txtNombre_Rele.getText().toString() + itemView.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_Rele01_ON),
                 //           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                if (!b) {
                    new enviarComandos().execute("http://" + txtIp.getText().toString() + "/?" + txtcmd_Off.getText().toString());
                   // btnActivarRele.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.btn_round_corner);
                   // Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),txtNombre_Rele.getText().toString() + itemView.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_Rele01_OFF),
                   //         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu `viewHolder` comentas la linea donde declaras un `toggleBtn` para ese `holder`, y entonces cuando instancias el `toggleBtn`, estas instanciando cada `toggleBtn` en la misma variable general de la clase `Adapter`, hasta que llega al último elemento de la lista, por ende es el que recibe la acción de todos los ítems.

Remueve la variable `btnActivarRele` del `adapter` y des comenta la del `ViewHolder`, y eso debería hacer que cada ítem de la lista se comporte como debe.

Cada ítem de la lista debe tener su propio contexto y no compartir variables con ninguna otra, o tendrás comportamientos muy extraños como el del botón.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ahora si funciona!!!. Pero ahora me surge otro problema. El ToggleButton lo declare en el Adapter para poder acceder a el desde onBindViewHolder. Ya que en función de un texto contenido en onBindViewHolder, cambio el estado del toggle. Ahora esto ya no es posible. Se te ocurre ¿como puedo acceder al toggle desde el onBindViewHolder?Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Llevo varios días con esto..

Comment: Quizas si usas en onBindViewHolder lo siguiente: miContenedor.btnActivarRele... asi accedes directamente al objeto del item, en vez de tener uno global. Lo mismo deberias  hacer con imagenFucionamiento por cierto.

Comment: Ok Sander, he modificado el código tal como me comentas y ya puedo acceder al toggle y modificar el estado desde el MyHolder. Gracias!!!